# Conditional statements in Ruby watir

Tags: ruby, watir

so I am completely new to watir. And I am basically trying to implement a conditional text checker. I am creating a testclass using watir. So for now; assuming we are given this simple example in which I have a global variable @target. And depending on what @target['color'] is, I want to check for a different string. This is how I would be doing it right now:

```
Browser.text.include?
 if @target['color'] == "red"
   "You got rubies."
 elsif @target['color'] == "green"
   "You got plants"
 else
   "You got nothing"
 end
```

I get syntax errors around the "red"/"green". And sometimes even on elsif

Any help would be appreciated. A good link to an article especially. I haven't found anything on conditionals of this sort. Makes me think that its not possible.

I also tried doing it with the Browser.text.include? inside the conditional branches. That did not work either.

Comment: Conditionals are a part of the underlying Ruby language that Watir is implemented in.  any of a variety of online tutorials for Ruby will include stuff on the various potential conditional statements.  For someone who knows ruby, the documentation that comes with the ruby language ought to suffice.  For someone entirely new to programming, I recommend the book 'Everyday Scripting with Ruby" by Brian Marick 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Browser.text.include? case @target['color']
    when "red" then "You got rubies."
    when "green" then "You got plants"
    else  "You got nothing"
end
```